# How to use python functions and variables inside XSLT?

Tags: python, xml, xslt, lxml

In PHP, you can use `registerPHPFunctions` to use a PHP function inside an XSLT file like this:

```
 <?php
$xml = <<<EOB
<allusers>
 <user>
  <uid>bob</uid>
  <id>1</id>
 </user>
 <user>
  <uid>joe</uid>
  <id>2</id>
 </user>
</allusers>
EOB;

$xsl = <<<EOB
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="allusers">
  <html><body>
    <h2>Users</h2>
    <table>
    <xsl:for-each select="user">
      <tr><td>
        <xsl:value-of
             select="php:function('ucfirst',concat(string(uid), string(id)))"/>
      </td></tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body></html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
EOB;
$xmldoc = DOMDocument::loadXML($xml);
$xsldoc = DOMDocument::loadXML($xsl);

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->registerPHPFunctions('ucfirst');
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsldoc);
echo $proc->transformToXML($xmldoc);
?>
```

What is the Python equivalent? This is what I've tried

```
from lxml import etree 

xml = etree.XML('''
<allusers>
 <user>
  <uid>bob</uid>
  <id>1</id>
 </user>
 <user>
  <uid>joe</uid>
  <id>2</id>
 </user>
</allusers>''')

xsl = etree.XML('''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:f="mynamespace"
     extension-element-prefixes="f">

<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="allusers">
  <html><body>
    <h2>Users</h2>
    <table>
    <xsl:for-each select="user">
      <tr><td>
        <f:ucfirst>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(string(uid), string(id))"/>
        </f:ucfirst>
      </td></tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body></html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
''')
extension = Ucase()
extensions = { ('mynamespace', 'ucfirst') : extension }
proc = etree.XSLT(xsl, extensions=extensions)
str(proc(xml))

class Ucase(etree.XSLTExtension):
  def execute(self, context, self_node, input_node, output_parent):
    title = self_node[0].text.capitalize()
    output_parent.text(title)
```

This is a simplified version of my XSLT.

Comment: Your PHP sample implements an extension function, your Python sample however seems to try to add an extension element. Is that what you intend to do in Python, implementing an extension element?

Comment: No, I just want to use a custom function inside an XSLT file. Either method is fine as long as it does the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how an extension function (not an element) can give the result that I think you want:

```
from lxml import etree

def ucfirst(context, s):
    return s.capitalize()

ns = etree.FunctionNamespace("mynamespace")
ns['ucfirst'] = ucfirst

xml = etree.XML('''
<allusers>
 <user>
  <uid>bob</uid>
  <id>1</id>
 </user>
 <user>
  <uid>joe</uid>
  <id>2</id>
 </user>
</allusers>''')

xsl = etree.XML('''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:f="mynamespace" exclude-result-prefixes="f">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="allusers">
  <html><body>
    <h2>Users</h2>
    <table>
    <xsl:for-each select="user">
      <tr><td>
        <xsl:value-of select="f:ucfirst(concat(string(uid), string(id)))"/>
      </td></tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body></html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
''')

transform = etree.XSLT(xsl)
result = transform(xml)
print result
```

Output:

```
<html><body>
<h2>Users</h2>
<table>
<tr><td>Bob1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Joe2</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

See http://lxml.de/extensions.html#xpath-extension-functions.

Comment: Consider to add `exclude-result-prefixes="f"` on the `xsl:stylesheet` to avoid littering the HTML result with the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

There are separate answers for variables and functions. I'm only really familiar with the variable half.

---

For variables, you can pass them as an `xsl:param` by passing them as keyword arguments to the call. For example:

```
transform = etree.XSLT(xslt_tree)
result = transform(doc_root, a="5")
```

Note that the argument is an XPath expression, so strings need to be quoted. There is a function that does this opaquely:

```
result = transform(doc_root, a=etree.XSLT.strparam(""" It's "Monty Python" """))
```

If you want to pass an XML fragment you could use the `exslt:node-set()` function.

---

For functions, you can expose them either as an xpath function or as an element. There is a bunch of variety and I haven't done this myself so read the docs below and/or edit this answer.

---

[Docs for basic use and variables.](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html)

[Docs for adding functions.](http://lxml.de/extensions.html)